# Conditional Variance equals zero

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, variance

Given two random variables Y and Z, I want to show that

$$
Var(Y|Z) = 0
$$

if and only if there exists a measurable function $h$ such that

$$
Y = h(Z).$$

From $Var(Y|Z) = 0$ I know that $E[Y^2|Z] = E[Y|Z]^2$, but I don't know what to make of this or how to continue from here.

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$ Var[Y|Z] = E[(Y-E[Y|Z])^2|Z] = 0$$

Since $(Y - E[Y|Z])^2 \geq 0$, its expectation equals to $0$ if and only if $(Y - E[Y|Z])^2 = 0$ almost surely, i.e. $Y = E[Y|Z]$ almost surely. By definition of conditional expectation, $E[Y|Z]$ is a $\sigma(Z)$-measurable function. And the last step of the claim should be similar to this:

[If $Y$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma (X)$ then there is a measurable function $f$ so $f(X)=Y$ - Stuck in Proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947052/if-y-is-measurable-with-respect-to-sigma-x-then-there-is-a-measurable-fun)