# Is there a Borel set $B \in \mathcal B_E$ such that $B \subset \operatorname{im} f$ and $\nu (B) = 1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, measurable-functions

In an attempt to extend [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947052/if-y-is-measurable-with-respect-to-sigma-x-then-there-is-a-measurable-fun) result to Banach spaces, I come across the existence of some Borel sets.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite complete measure space. Let $(E,|\cdot|)$ be a Banach space and $\mathcal B_E$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $f:\Omega \to E$ be [$\mu$-measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306079/a-function-f-is-mu-measurable-if-and-only-if-f-is-mathcal-a-measurable?noredirect=1&lq=1) theorem, $f$ is $\mathcal F$-$\mathcal B_E$ measurable. Let $\nu:= f_\sharp \mu$ be the push-forward measure. This means $\nu$ is a Borel probability measure on $E$.

Is there a Borel set $B \in \mathcal B_E$ such that $B \subset \operatorname{im} f := f(\Omega)$ and $\nu (B) = 1$?

Thank you for your elaboration!

---

**Update:** I have found a closely related question to the one above: Is there a $\mu$-measurable function $g:\Omega \to E$ such that $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e. such that $g(\Omega) \in \mathcal B_E$?

Comment: You need some conditions on $f$ for the question to be interesting I guess. If $f$ maps into a single point $\nu$ will exactly attain the values $0$ and $\mu(\Omega)$. You probably also want more conditions on $\mu$ because for the statement to hold you, at the bare minimum, need a set $F\in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mu(F)=1$.

Comment: @JonathanHole Could you more elaborate more on " If $f$ maps into a single point $\nu$ will exactly attain the values $0$ and $\mu (\Omega)$" and on what $F$ means?